# Laravel 5.1 show indexes for existing folders

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have a problem with Laravel 5.1 routing, If I try to make a route with the same name that a folder in the /public folder apache shows me the index of the folder (I have forbidden indexes so it shows a Forbidden message) I don't know if it's impossible to make it work, I have obviously changed the name of the assets folder with the conflictive name in public directory, but it would be awesome if I could name it as I want.

If I wans unclear (because my bad english) the short explanation is the following:
I have a "game" folder in the /public folder of Laravel 5.1
I want to have a route named /game (example.com/game)
When I acces to /game apache shows me the index of the folder, instead of redirect me to index.php as rewrite rules do.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess file there is something like this: if there is no file or directory for the URL then give the URL to laravel.

Just remove the directory check and it should work fine. (Please post your htaccess file so I can tell you what line you have to remove)

Comment: This is my htpaccess: http://pastebin.com/Dy37vYz2
I have commented the line 13 and it works perfect, many thanks ;D